# Connecting ESP01 to arduino to control servo motors

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-esp32

I am trying to control six servo motors with a website using an Arduino Uno and a ESP01 module.
The ESP01 is connected to the Arduino via Software Serial and I am using AT commands.
Each Servo represents one person and has 8 positions.
The person and position are handed over in a GET request in this format: "xx = y", xx representing the person an y the postion.
The problem is that sometimes the GET request is not read properly.
For example "ni = 3" is read as "oi = 3".
Can someone tell me, why this is happening and how I can fix that?
This is my first time using ESP01 and HTTP, so I am a bit lost.
Thanks a lot!

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3); //set ESP8266 RX pin = 2, and TX pin = 3
#define DEBUG true //display ESP8266 messages on Serial Monitor

int Pos_Ka[]= {8,30,53,75,100,122,144,165};
int Pos_Th[]= {3,30,51,77,98,124,146,169};
int Pos_Bl[]= {18,45,68,90,114,137,160,180};
int Pos_Mc[]= {11,33,56,78,102,125,155,173};
int Pos_Ni[]= {5,30,53,74,103,121,146,170};
int Pos_Bu[]= {8,30,55,78,102,124,146,171};
int Ort[] = {Pos_Ka[3], Pos_Th[3], Pos_Bl[3], Pos_Mc[3], Pos_Ni[3], Pos_Bu[3]};

//Servo Einstellungen
int vel = 10;
int minimum_position = 2; 
int maximum_position = 180;
//
Servo kampenholz;//Erstellt für das Programm ein Servo mit dem Namen „kampenholz"
Servo theemin; //Erstellt für das Programm ein Servo mit dem Namen „theemin"
Servo blackthorn; //Erstellt für das Programm ein Servo mit dem Namen „blackthorn"
Servo mclynn; //Erstellt für das Programm ein Servo mit dem Namen „mclynn"
Servo nightshade; //Erstellt für das Programm ein Servo mit dem Namen „nightshade"
Servo burbage; //Erstellt für das Programm ein Servo mit dem Namen „burbage"

void setup() {
//Servo start settings
  kampenholz.attach(6); 
  kampenholz.write(Ort[0]);
  delay(100);
  kampenholz.detach();
  
  theemin.attach(7); 
  theemin.write(Ort[1]);
  delay(100);
  theemin.detach();
  
  blackthorn.attach(8);
  blackthorn.write(Ort[2]);
  delay(100);
  blackthorn.detach();

  mclynn.attach(9); 
  mclynn.write(Ort[5]);
  delay(100);
  mclynn.detach();
    
  nightshade.attach(10); 
  nightshade.write(Ort[4]);
  delay(100);
  nightshade.detach();

  burbage.attach(11); 
  burbage.write(Ort[3]);
  delay(100);
  burbage.detach();

  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  // Connect to Wi-Fi network
  sendData("AT+RST\r\n", 2000, DEBUG); //reset module
  sendData("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); //set station mode
  sendData("AT+CWJAP=\"LIST-ORGA\",\"##xxx##\"\r\n", 2000, DEBUG);   //connect wifi network
  while(!esp8266.find("OK")) { //wait for connection
  } 
  sendData("AT+CIFSR\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); //show IP address
  sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); //allow multiple connections
  sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); // start web server on port 80
}

void loop() {
    if (esp8266.available()) {      //check if there is data available on ESP8266
    if (esp8266.find("+IPD,")) {    //if there is a new command
    Serial.println("Neuer Befehl");
      String ganz = esp8266.readStringUntil("\r\n\r\n");
      Serial.println(ganz);
      String prof = ganz.substring(11,13);
      Serial.println("Prof:");
      Serial.println(prof);
      String ortString = ganz.substring(14,15);
      Serial.println("Ort:");
      Serial.println(ortString);
      int ort = ortString.toInt();
      esp8266.find("?"); //run cursor until command is found
      delay(500);
      esp8266.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n\r\n <br> Hallo");
   
      //************
      // move servos
      //************
     if (prof == "ka"){
      kampenholz.attach(6);
      kampenholz.write(Pos_Ka[ort-1]);
      delay(100);
      kampenholz.detach();
      Ort[0]=Pos_Ka[ort-1];
     }

     if (prof == "th"){
      theemin.attach(7);
      theemin.write(Pos_Th[ort-1]);
      delay(100);
      theemin.detach();
      Ort[0]=Pos_Th[ort-1];
     }

    if (prof == "bl"){
      blackthorn.attach(8);
      blackthorn.write(Pos_Bl[ort-1]);
      delay(100);
      blackthorn.detach();
      Ort[0]=Pos_Bl[ort-1];
     }

    if (prof == "mc"){
      mclynn.attach(9);
      mclynn.write(Pos_Mc[ort-1]);
      delay(100);
      mclynn.detach();
      Ort[0]=Pos_Mc[ort-1];
     }

    if (prof == "ni"){
      nightshade.attach(10);
      nightshade.write(Pos_Ni[ort-1]);
      delay(100);
      nightshade.detach();
      Ort[0]=Pos_Ni[ort-1];
     }

    if (prof == "bu"){
      burbage.attach(11);
      burbage.write(Pos_Bu[ort-1]);
      delay(100);
      burbage.detach();
      Ort[0]=Pos_Bu[ort-1];
     }
    }
  }
}


//********************
// Auxiliary functions
//********************

//send data to ESP8266
String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug){
  String response = "";
  esp8266.print(command);
  long int time = millis();
  while ( (time + timeout) > millis())
  {
    while (esp8266.available())
    {
      char c = esp8266.read();
      response += c;
    }
  }
  if (debug)
  {
    Serial.print(response);
  }
  return response;
}
```

Comment: Your question and supplied code have nothing to do with HTML.